# Performance slowness while hitting gRPC endpoints first time using protobuf-net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, protobuf-net, netcoreapp3.1, protobuf-net.grpc

I have a gRPC server running using the protobuf-net.gRPC using .NET Core 3.1. It uses ASP.NET Core framework and Kestrel behind the scenes to run the HTTP server. I notice that very first time the gRPC endpoints that are hit on this server spend substantially more time in the ASP NET Core middleware compared to subsequent calls on the same endpoint.

```
Time taken from 
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[ExecutedEndPoint] : Executing endpoint 'gRPC - /grpc.....'

Until hitting the actual endpoint function in my gRPC server
```

Time taken for the first time is quite high around 30-40 Ma while the subsequent calls to the same endpoint is around 1-2 ms.

Is this because of the JIT compiler compiling from IL->Native code ? If so, is there an way to get around this first time performance issue other than the obvious means such as forcibly calling the endpoints ?

Regards

Comment: First request taking longer than subsequent request isn't really surprising to me. I guess it's just the gRPC server-side stack warming up. Also, this might not be a gRPC specific thing, it might behave similarly when new HTTP/2 handlers in ASP.NET core are used for the first time.  I found similar discussion here: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/17985 (which might give you the answers you need).

Answer (score 0):

This could be due to the gRPC design as the channel's connection is not established until the first RPC call is issued.

The 30-40 ms is probably for opening TCP connection + SSL handshake + HTTP/2 settings frames exchange. The following RPC calls reuse this channel/connection and thus don't have this overhead.

For Java there is an experimental API [getState](https://grpc.github.io/grpc-java/javadoc/io/grpc/ManagedChannel.html#getState-boolean-) that a client can call with a requestConnection = true argument right after channel creation to initiate the connection. Not sure if it's available in C#.

Comment: I see that this 30-40ms is not specific to a client. This happens for the very first time a specific endpoint is hit on the gRPC server. So if I have 2 enpoints - /grpc/endpoint1, /grpc/endpoint2, first calls to /grpc/endpoint1 and /grpc/endpoint2 incur 30-40ms each. Also if a client1 calls /grpc/endpoint1 it takes 30-40ms, if a client2 calls /grpc/endpoint1 after this it takes only a few ms. so this is not specific to a client